# Output file content same as direct access?

Tags: php, file, filesystems, file-access

I have a file on server named 'file.pdf' and I can't directly access it like this: 
`servername.com/file.pdf`,
because it's in upper level of folder that servername.com redirects to.

I need to use php to obtain file and then output, so it would look like this:
`servername.com/get_file.php?filename=file.pdf`

This is what I tried, however, it doesn't work:

```
<?php
    $filename = $_GET['filename'];
    header('Location: ../seedbox/downloads/knygos' . $filename);
?>
```

Any solution on how I can access that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your "solution" you're making the exact same error again. You're again trying to access a file directly via HTTP which is below your web root (public folder, httpdocs, ...).

You are already proposing the right solution, namely to fetch the file with PHP and serve it but then you're not doing it. You have two main solutions for the problem:

**Move the file to a public location**

Here you can either permanently change the file location to something like `mysite.com/downloads/file.pdf` or [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) it there dynamically with PHP:

```
copy('../files/file.pdf', 'downloads/file.pdf');
```

**Serve the file on the fly**

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.pdf");

readfile('../files/file.pdf');
```